# Marklogic 8 Node.js API - phrase searches

Tags: node.js, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm trying to apply search on film titles using a structured query applied to json objects.

Let's imagine a film titled **"Marius et Jeannette"**.

```
db.documents.query( qb.where( qb.word('title','Marius') )
```

or

```
db.documents.query( qb.where( qb.word('title','Marius et Jeannette') )
```

both give results.

but

```
db.documents.query( qb.where( qb.word('title','Marius Jeannette') )
```

does not.

Is there a way to configure a "near query" using the node.js API? I did not find anything on this subject in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

The QueryBuilder supports the near query:

http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#near

Do you have a case where that isn't working?

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 0):

I believe your sample can be done with "Maruis **NEAR** Jeanette"

Check out the node.js string query section [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_84672) under the section titled: *Searching with String Queries*

Comment: Does not seems so (I just tried). Such operators seem to be dedicated to  string queries (qb.parsedFrom()), and not available is stuctured queries.

Comment: I manage to get things running with a binding, but this will imply some string manipulation, if not other solution arises:     qb.parsedFrom('title:Marius title:Jeannette)',
      qb.parseBindings(
        qb.word(qb.field('filmTitle'), qb.bind('title'))
      )
    )